# How to print a map? And make it a global variable? C++

Tags: c++, variables, printing, dictionary, global

For Windows 7 64-bit
So I set up my map

```
    map<string, string> database;
    database["user"] = "123";
```

It's part of the main function, but how can I print the contents of the map? And most importantly how can it be turned into a global variable so I can use it by other functions? I'm trying to put my printing map process in a different function than where the map was made.

Comment: and i set both the key and value as strings because the value is supposed to represent the password to the key which is a username, so it can contain words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

// this will be a global variable
map<string, string> database;

int main()
{

    database["user"] = "123";

    map<string, string>::iterator it;
    for(it = database.begin(); it!= database.end(); it++)
    {
        pair<string, string> p = *it;
        cout << "key=\"" << p.first << "\" value=\"" << p.second << "\"" << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have done this and if I have several other keys in the map, it only prints the one that is under the current jey being used for my login system. Anyway thanks for the global variable thing, I did that before but somehow messed it up.//// Hahaha never mind. I was doing something weird in the code itself, calling a system pause lol. my bad. it works. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through map with following code:

```
for(auto it = database.begin(); it != database.end(); ++it) {
  // it->first is your key
  // it->second is value of particular key
  std::cout << "Key: " << it->first << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Value: " << it->second << std::endl;
  // value can be reached as follows as well
  std::cout << "Value: " << database[it->first] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise to use C++11 features, like for_each, range based *begin* and *end* and *lambda*:

```
std::for_each(std::begin(database), std::end(database), 
              [&database](std::pair<std::string, std::string> p) {
    std::cout << "Key : " << p.first << "\tValue : " << p.second << std::endl;
});
```

Second I'd avoid to make your map a global variable. There are reasons for global definitions, but for a container? (This maybe depends how big your project is, but I'd say let's get rid of any global variable, and if it is really needed put it inside a namespace)

Why not encapsulate your map into a class and provide functions to alter the content of your map, even your printing facility? If you want to make sure, that every user of your class shall have the same content of the map (translated this means the same instance), you can turn your class into a singleton.

Comment: I can do this on a new project but for now I'll stick to that because I'm new to C++ and I don't know that much about making classes and objects and stuff. but I'll give it a shot afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you have C++1 available (and as a sidenote to Stefan's answer: You don't actually need `std::for_each` or lambdas in C++11), iteration can be done using range based for:

```
for ( std::pair<std::string,std::string> const &p : database)
   std::cout << "key=\"" << p.first << "\" value=\"" << p.second << "\"" << std::endl;
```

If you want to use it in other functions, think about several things instead of making the variable global:

- Aggreate/incapsulate all functions using the database in a class
- Pass the map object to your functions